# match and exclude links from rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, preg-match

I know how to exclude folders, file types but i don't know how to exclude a link that contain a specific word.
I have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://en.domain.com/$1 [QSA,L]
```

How to exclude from this rule the links that have at beginning: index.php?a=admin

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^a=admin
RewriteRule (.*) http://en.domain.com/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here, we're adding a condition that states that the rewrite may only occur if the host is `www.domain.com`, the file being requested is `index.php`, and the query string does not being with `a=admin`.

So, `www.domain.com/test` will redirect to `en.domain.com/test`, but `www.domain.com/index.php?a=admin` will not redirect at all.